# For i LOOP PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

EDITED.

I have a question regarding looping and inserting data to MYSQL .

Im creating an archival system which is a part of my internship program, what the system does is to store data regarding box and files. Each boxes can contain 1 or multiple files .

```
    <form>
<input type="text" maxlength="2" name="box_number[]" placheholder="Box No" />
<input type="text" name="item_name[]" placeholder="Item name"  /></td>
    </form>
```

The user need to specify which item goes to which boxes like below :

```
        box_number = 1 , Name= Item 1   
        box_number = 1 , Name= Item 2

        box_number = 2 , Name= Item 3
        box_number = 2 , Name= Item 4

        box_number = 3 , Name= Item 5
```

I have 2 tables which is BOX and BOX_DATA .  BOX Contains (PK)Box_ID which is Auto-generated and is linked to Box_Data's Box_ID (FK).

The previous problem has been solved thanks to Gayan which is to have distinct id based on box numbers but another problem rises where i couldn't link the Box_ID from Table BOX to foreign key (Box_ID) from table Box_DATA

These are my form codes :

```
  <SCRIPT src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></SCRIPT>
    <script>
    function addMore() {
        $("<table>").load("input.php", function() {
                $("#product").append($(this).html());
        }); 
    }

    function deleteRow() {
        $('tr').each(function(index, item){
            jQuery(':checkbox', this).each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $(item).remove();
                }
            });
        });
    }

    </script>


    <form id="form" method="post" action="submit_request.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div style="border:black 1px solid;padding:10px;border-radius:20px;background:silver;">
       <strong>** INSTRUCTIONS **</strong><br /> 
       <strong>** Please refer and follow the format below. **</strong> <br />
       <strong> For example:-  3 boxes , Box 1 (2 items) , Box 2 (1 item) and Box 3 (1 item). </strong> <br />   
       <strong> Box No : 1 , File Name : Item 1  </strong> <br />
       <strong> Box No : 1 , File Name : Item 2  </strong> <br />
       <strong> Box No : 2 , File Name : Item 3  </strong> <br />
       <strong> Box No : 3 , File Name : Item 4  </strong> <br />   
       </div>

<div>
<table id="product" >
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Box No:</th>
<th>File Name:</th>
<th>From</th>
<th>To</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ><input type="checkbox" name="item_index[]" /></td>
<td><input class="form-control input-md" style="width:50px;" type="text" maxlength="2" name="box_number[]" placheholder="Box No" required="required"/></td>
<td><input class="form-control input-md" type="text" name="item_name[]" placeholder="File name" required="required" /></td>
<td><input class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Year from" maxlength="4"  name="date_from[]" /></td>
<td><input class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Year to" maxlength="4" name="date_to[]" /></td>
<td><textarea class="form-control input-md" cols="50" rows="5" name="description[]" placeholder="Any information on this file "></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="row">       
<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-md"  type="button" name="add_item" value="Add More Files" onClick="addMore();" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-md"  type="button" name="del_item" value="Delete" onClick="deleteRow();" />
</div>    
</div>  
</div>
```

<---------------- Code below is the submit_request --->

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$uniqueItems = array_unique($_POST["box_number"]);

foreach($uniqueItems as $key => $uniqueItem) {
// using $uniqueItem you can persists to the database...
$stmt_box =$db->prepare("insert into box(date_created)values(:date_created)");
$stmt_box ->bindParam(':date_created',$date);
$stmt_box ->execute();
$last_box_id= $db->lastInsertId();  

}

if(!empty($_POST["item_name"])){
    $itemCount = count($_POST["item_name"]);
    $itemValues=0;
    $query = "INSERT INTO box_data (items,box_id) VALUES ";
    $queryValue = "";

for($i=0;$i<$itemCount;$i++) {

if(!empty($_POST["item_name"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["box_number"][$i])) {
                $itemValues++;
                if($queryValue!="") {  $queryValue .= ","; }
                $queryValue .= "('" . $_POST["item_name"][$i] . $last_box_id. "')";                     
            }
            $sql = $query.$queryValue;              
        }

        if($itemValues!=0) {
            $result = $db->prepare($sql);
                $result->execute();
                print json_encode($sql);
                print json_encode($stmt);

        }}}
```

I dont know where to put the last inserted id , is it relevant or not. Because what im getting so far is

```
  TABLE BOX 
                Box_ID  | Date |
                1       | 2017 |         <- box_number = 1 , Item= Item 1 and 2
                2       | 2017 |         <- box_number = 1 , Item= Item 3 and 4
                3       | 2017 |         <- box_number = 2 , Item= Item 5

TABLE BOX_DATA 
            Items  | Box_ID | Date |
            Item 1 |   3    | 2017 |     <- this is what i get
            Item 2 |   3    | 2017 |         
            Item 3 |   3    | 2017 |     
            Item 4 |   3    | 2017 |         
            Item 5 |   3    | 2017 |
```

<------ Below is what im trying to achieve-------->
  ## Heading ##

```
TABLE BOX 
                Box_ID  | Date |
                1       | 2017 |         <- box_number = 1 , Item= Item 1 and 2
                2       | 2017 |         <- box_number = 1 , Item= Item 3 and 4
                3       | 2017 |         <- box_number = 2 , Item= Item 5

    TABLE BOX_DATA 
                Items  | Box_ID | Date |
                Item 1 |   1    | 2017 |     <- This is what im trying to achieve
                Item 2 |   1    | 2017 |         
                Item 3 |   2    | 2017 |     
                Item 4 |   2    | 2017 |         
                Item 5 |   3    | 2017 |
```

Comment: The statements in both the `if` and `else` look exactly the same, why are you duplicating that code? You also don't need to keep prepareing the same statement. Prepare it just once. And you're not changing any of the variables you're binding, so it inserts the same thing every time.

Comment: Statements like `$i+2; $j+2;` don't so anything.

Comment: You shouldn't have nested loops like in the first code block. Just one loop that processes all the inputs. But you're not using any of the input data in the `INSERT` queries.

Comment: This question is incredibly confusing. Please show what the HTML really looks like, the database schema, and what rows should get inserted into the DB.

Comment: sorry , hope the edited version is suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is first isolate the unique `box_numbers` and then persists.

```
$uniqueItems = array_unique($_POST["box_number"])

foreach($uniqueItems as $key => $uniqueItem) {
    // using $uniqueItem you can persists to the database...
}
```

Your explanation is quite difficult to understand, I guise this is the solution you're looking for

Comment: thanks for the solution but it raise another problem